# How to create a dynamic storage class in OCP 3.11?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

When I try to run a script for OCP 3.11 I get this error

> At least one dynamic storage class must be available in order to proceed.

How can I create this dynamic storage class?

Comment: Hi there! Can you please share with us your inventory file where you define your storage class? Are you using GlusterFS?

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas, I don't know where I can find the inventory file.  Not GlusterFS, I have to setup NFS Server and client.

Comment: What script did you run and which infrastructure are you using? StorageClass doesn't work by itself only. It needs to work with a storage provisioner plugin e.g. cinder, aws-ebs, gce-pd.

Comment: @hiroyukik I am having 3 nodes, but I don't know if it is 1 infra or 1 worker or 2 worker nodes. Can you tell how can I determine if node is infra or worker?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I talked about an infrastructure like AWS, GCP and Baremetal. You may find some ideas to use Dynamic Provisioning.
[1]: https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/persistent_storage/dynamically_provisioning_pvs.html#available-dynamically-provisioned-plug-ins

Comment: How you installed OKD? Is this a Minishift installation?

Comment: I used a template/stencil provided in a VM which had OKD already installed. I am following this document for installing NFS - https://medium.com/faun/openshift-dynamic-nfs-persistent-volume-using-nfs-client-provisioner-fcbb8c9344e . I have one master/infra node and 2 worker nodes. After following the document and running the command `oc get pods` - I am getting the nfs provisioner client in **ContainerRunning** state. How to change it to **RunningState** ?